# JAWS Screen Reader Repeats Tree Items in FireFox

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I have run into an issue with the JAWS screen reader & Firefox.

I have a tree like the one below. Whenever any of the `<a>` elements gain focus, either by tabbing from the window or from the `<button>`, JAWS **narrates the element three times**. As far as i can tell, Firefox is the only browser that does this.

Is there something wrong with my markup here?

```
<nav role="tree">
  <ol role="group">
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="treeitem">Parent Link 1</a>
      <ol role="group">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="treeitem">Child Link 1</a>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="treeitem">Child Link 2</a>
      </ol>
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="treeitem">Parent Link 2</a>
      <ol role="group">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="treeitem">Child Link 3</a>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="treeitem">Child Link 4</a>
      </ol>
  </ol>
</nav>

<button>Something else to focus on</button>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, i have found the answer after asking the question. :(

Evidently, if i move `role="tree"` from the outer `<nav>` to the first `<ol>`, Firefox narrates as expected. The markup now looks like this:

```
<nav>
  <ol role="tree">
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="treeitem">Parent Link 1</a>
      <ol role="group">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="treeitem">Child Link 1</a>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="treeitem">Child Link 2</a>
      </ol>
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="treeitem">Parent Link 2</a>
      <ol role="group">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="treeitem">Child Link 3</a>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="treeitem">Child Link 4</a>
      </ol>
  </ol>
</nav>

<button>Something else to focus on</button>
```

This smells like a bug in Firefox to me. [I have opened a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1217087) & will follow an developments.

Answer (score 1):

You should at the very least be using `aria-owns` to show the relationship between the parent and the child. Take a look at this example http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/42/

Also, it would be better to actually just use the hierarchical list item structure that you already have. See this example: http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/41/

If you have done that and still have problems, try it with NVDA instead of JAWS. NVDA is more standards compliant than JAWS.

Comment: `aria-owns` is not necessary because `treeitem` is a descendent of its `group` (unlike example 42).

I am not sure what you mean by "use the hierarchical list structure you already have". The code above is structured very similarly to example 41, with that example being more complete obviously.

Comment: I may mis-understand your structure, but if Paret Link 1 is a parent of Child Link 1 then it needs `aria-owns` or it needs to be the hierarchical parent of that element (and all other children)

Comment: You're right. I confused myself. Unfortunately, this change did not resolve the underlying issue with JAWS.

Comment: Do you get the same problem with JAWS and the examples I sent you?

Comment: No,  i do not. My guess is because in the examples,  `role=tree` is on the `<ul>`,  not a `<nav>`.  I don't think that should make a difference, so I think is a JAWS and/or Firefox bug.