# How to have a parent treeitem in a treeview be a link

Tags: html, hyperlink, tree, accessibility, wai-aria

The [treeview example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/examples/treeview/treeview-2/treeview-2a.html) of the [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/#TreeView) shows how to have a tree with some items being expandable parent nodes, and some being hyperlinks:

```html
<ul role="tree" aria-label="Foods">
  <li role="treeitem" aria-expanded="true">
    <span> Fruits </span>
    <ul role="group">
      <li role="none"> <a role="treeitem" href="/orange"> Oranges </a> </li>
      <li role="none"> <a role="treeitem" href="/pineapple"> Pineapple </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

However, what if I want to have a "Fruits" page too, and have a treeitem that is both a parent node and a hyperlink?

(For keyboard navigation, the pattern of `Right Arrow`/`Left Arrow` opening/closing the parent node, and `Enter` following the hyperlink would be used. This resembles the interaction of a [combobox with a tree popup](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/#tree-popup-keyboard-interaction).

For mouse interaction, the current pattern would be kept: having a clickable icon (`aria-hidden`) indicating expanded state, which opens/closes the node, and the text of the link itself, which follows the link.)

For example:

```html
<ul role="tree" aria-label="Foods">
  <li role="none">
    <a role="treeitem" aria-expanded="true" href="/fruits">
      <span> Fruits </span>
      <ul role="group">
        <li role="none"> <a role="treeitem" href="/orange"> Oranges </a> </li>
        <li role="none"> <a role="treeitem" href="/pineapple"> Pineapple </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This, while technically correct, violates the HTML spec, which disallows `<a>` tags being nested within other `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33347881/3067153), which is about a different topic and only hints at my solution.

To have the `<a>` element be the `treeitem`, while simultaneously "containing" other `<a>` elements nested within groups, the `aria-owns` attribute can be used.

Like this, the requirement that

> Each parent node contains or owns an element with role group.

is satisfied, while at the same time following the HTML spec.

```html
<ul role="tree" aria-label="Foods">
  <li role="none">
    <a role="treeitem" aria-expanded="true" aria-owns="fruit-group" href="/fruits">
      <span> Fruits </span>
    </a>
    <ul role="group" id="fruit-group">
      <li role="none"> <a role="treeitem" href="/orange"> Oranges </a> </li>
      <li role="none"> <a role="treeitem" href="/pineapple"> Pineapple </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you are looking for but I thought I would share it for anyone that is looking for something similar that accomplishes the same thing at least from the end user's perspective.

The following code has been modified from w3school's Tree View Example to have clickable arrows and parent link items besides them.

Original code: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_treeview.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
ul, #myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}

.caret::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.caret-down::before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */'
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Tree View</h2>
<p>A tree view represents a hierarchical view of information, where each item can have a number of subitems.</p>
<p>Click on the arrow(s) to open or close the tree branches.</p>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><span class="caret"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drink">Beverages</a></span>
    <ul class="nested">
    <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water">Water</a></li>
      <li><span class="caret">Juice</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>Orange Juice</li>
          <li>Apple Juice</li>
        </ul>
      </li>   <!-- End of caret Tea -->
       <li><span class="caret">Tea</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>Black Tea</li>
          <li>White Tea</li>
          <li><span class="caret"></span><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_tea">Green Tea</a>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li>Sencha</li>
              <li>Gyokuro</li>
              <li>Matcha</li>
              <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>   <!-- End of caret Tea -->
    </ul> <!-- End of nested -->
  </li> <!-- End of caret Beverage -->
</ul> <!-- End of myUL -->

<script>
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works for mouse users, yeah - my question was specifically about keyboard/screen reader users and WCAG compliance.